How can I call a different pallet function in benchmark?
I want to call a function from different pallet say "pallet_departments"
    assert_ok!(<pallet_departments::Pallet<T>>::create_department(
            RawOrigin::Signed(caller).into(),
            content_department
        ));

It gives error:
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `create_department` exists for struct `Pallet<T>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
    --> /home/amiya/Documents/workspace/shivarthu/working_directory/substrate-node-template/custom-pallets/department-funding/src/benchmarking.rs:36:47
     |
  36 |         assert_ok!(<pallet_departments::Pallet<T>>::create_department(
     |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `Pallet<T>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
     |
     = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
             `T: pallet_departments::Config`
  help: consider restricting the type parameter to satisfy the trait bound
     |
  18 |     fn create_department_required_fund() where T: pallet_departments::Config
     |                                          +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  error[E0599]: the function or associated item `create_department` exists for struct `Pallet<T>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
    --> /home/amiya/Documents/workspace/shivarthu/working_directory/substrate-node-template/custom-pallets/department-funding/src/benchmarking.rs:36:47
     |
  36 |         assert_ok!(<pallet_departments::Pallet<T>>::create_department(
     |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `Pallet<T>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
     |
     = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
             `T: pallet_departments::Config`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
  warning: `pallet-department-funding` (lib) generated 1 warning
  error: could not compile `pallet-department-funding` (lib) due to 2 previous errors; 1 warning emitted

Adding where T: pallet_departments::Config doesn't work.

Can I see the error after adding the trait bound for T? Does your mock runtime implement pallet_departments::Config? Cleanest way is to implement a BenchmarkHelper

Using where clause worked:
#[benchmarks(
         where T: pallet_departments::Config + frame_system::Config
)]


If this works, please mark it as the answer.
